# C# code to fill color in a table cell in a word document

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have created a word document which contains a table, using C#.
Now I want to fill one of the cells in this table with red color.
While searching on the net, I found that I could use the shading object to do this. But I dint get any details on how I could use this.

I tried using something like:

```
doc.Tables[whichTable].Cell(1,4).Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor
```

But how can I set a color using this???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at this [reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223960%28v=office.11%29.aspx) you will see the WdColor constants listed. These are colours available to word, to see more about them there is an enumeration listing [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb237558%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Your code to select the table cell looks correct to me, so you just need to set the BackgroundPatternColor to one of the WdColors.